# How do I access servlets after deploying to AWS Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: java, tomcat, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I set up a local test server (Tomcat 7) for my application that hosted my java servlets. The URL I used to grab data was 127.0.0.1:8080/backend/get. Now I have exported the eclipse project into a .war file and deployed it to EB, however I get 404 errors when trying the following URLs: my-env.elasticbeanstalk.com/get, my-env.elasticbeanstalk.com/backend/get.

How is EB deploying the .war and how can I access it from my client code?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I think you don't need to export your project to a .war file. Are you using Eclipse IDE? Because I could deploy my web application easily through eclipse.
[Here is the reference link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSToolkitEclipse/latest/GettingStartedGuide/deploy_using_elastic_beanstalk.html)

Suggestion: Use Java 1.6 version for you web application.

I think EB support JAVA 1.6 pretty good, while I'm not sure whether it works for Java 1.7. Because while I use JAVA 1.7 it works well locally, but I cannot deploy that version on EB.